# Unable to test color change on hover event

Tags: hover, cypress

I am trying to test a hover event that should change the font color of a link in my chess app. I know it works as it changes from white to purple when I run it and test it manually on my local host, but Cypress can't verify the change. Here is the test I wrote:

```js
  it('changes link color on hover', function () {
    cy.get('.ig-link').should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');

    cy.get('.ig-link')
      .trigger('mouseover')
      .should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(173, 6, 173)');
  });
```

And a screenshot of the test runner:[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `.realHover()` command in [cypress-real-events](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events#cyrealhover) works with this test

```js
cy.get('.ig-link')
  // .trigger('mouseover')
  .realHover()
  .should('have.css', 'color', 'rgb(173, 6, 173)');   // passes
```

Install with

```js
npm install cypress-real-events
//or
yarn add cypress-real-events
```

and add the register command to `cypress/support/e2e.js`

```js
import "cypress-real-events/support";
```